# fs.writeFile corrupting json files

Tags: node.js, json, node.js-fs

I have a program that writes a lot of files very quickly, and I noticed that sometimes there will be extra brackets or text in json files sometimes.
Here is how the program works:
There is an array of emojis with some more information, and if that emoji doesn't already have a file for itself, it creates a new one. If there already is an existing file of that name, it will edit it.
Code to write file:

```js
function writeToFile(fileName, file){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(file, null, 2), 'utf8', function(err) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

I have tried using fs and graceful-fs and both have had this issue every couple hundred files, with no visible patterns.
examples off messed up json:

```json
...
      ],
      "trade_times": []
    }
  ]
}ade_times": []
    }
  ]
}
```

That second "ade_times" shouldnt be there, and I have no idea why it is appearing.
other times it just looks like this:

```json
{
...
}}
```

with extra closing brackets for no reason.
Not sure if this is an issue with my code, with fs, or something with my pc. If you need any more information I can provide that (more code, node.js version, etc).
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: First off, you can just use `fs.promises.writeFile()` - you don't need to make your own promise function.  Second, a common cause of corrupted files is multiple pieces of code or multiple requests trying to write to the same file at the same time.  `fs.writeFile()` is not atomic.  It consists of multiple separate asycnhronous operations `fs.open()`, `fs.write()` and `fs.close()` so other requests on your server can intervene and cause corrupted file.  You may need to implement some sort of semaphore flag or promise that prevent this from happening.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know why your code is buggy.
But, I have created an alternate `writeToFile` function for you:

```js
// Async functions are functions that return a promise in a more concise way.
async function writeToFile(filename, file) {
     let fj = JSON.stringify(file, undefined, 2)
     // fs.readFileSync will automatically reject the promise with the error when it encounters an error
     fs.writeFileSync(filename, fj, {
          encoding: "utf8"
     })
     return // This line is the equivalent of resolve(), this line is optional too.
}
```

Hope this answer works for you